# How can i get display:none element using Selenium Webdriver c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxcia.jpg)

Please provide me the scripting code in C# to get the text of the element that are marked in blue box. I am using Selenium Web driver and I want to get the value:10975 in the td tag.

I tried the following code:

```
         IWebElement tableLocator = divLocator.FindElement(table);
         IWebElement tbodyFind = tableLocator.FindElement(tbodytag);
         driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(trTag));
         List<IWebElement> trList = tbodyFind.FindElements(trTag).ToList();
         driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
         wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(tdTag));
         //List<IWebElement> tdList = trList[1].FindElements(tdTag).ToList();
         IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]")));
        IWebElement hiddenElem = trList[0].FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/section/form/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]"));
```

Comment: Please post code as *text*, not as an image.

Comment: How can i get the element that is declared as display:none?
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none">54</td>
<td role="gridcell" style="display:none">10975</td>

Comment: I have taken all the td in a list but it could not find the hidden elements. I have also tried with xpath @guy

Comment: Add what you tried to your question including the code you wrote, that way it will be easier to help you.

Comment: code has been added @guy

Answer (score 6):

`Selenium` simulates user actions. If the element is not visible and the user can't read it, `Selenium` can't read it as well. To avoid this problem we can use the `WebElement` attributes.

```
IList<IWebElement> hiddenElements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".k-master-row > [style=display:none]"));
string text = hiddenElements[1].GetAttribute("textContent");
```

You should have the two hidden elements in the list. Just access the second by index and get the text.