# Selenium and eCharts - Struggling to parse text showed as a popup

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi am trying to parse text that appears as a popup when hovering on elements in a given eChart. I can see the text I am looking for in the HTML.
I'm using Selenium and C#.

I tried all the methods and combinations but Selenium usually retrieves an IWebElement without text.

This is the piece of html in the page I'm parsing:

```html
<div style="position: absolute; display: none; border-style: solid; white-space: nowrap; z-index: 9999999; transition: left 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0s, top 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0s; background-color: rgb(34, 34, 34); border-width: 0px; border-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-radius: 4px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font: 14px / 21px &quot;Microsoft YaHei&quot;; padding: 10px; left: -63px; top: -15px; pointer-events: none;">Failures: 2<br>Execution Date: 2020-07-16 17:28</div>
```

I'm trying to parse the "Failures: 2" and "Execution Date: 2020-07-16 17:28" strings

I tried the following commands:

var hover1 = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div style[text() = 'Failures: 2']"));

var hover1 = _driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(., 'Failures:')]"));

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: first problem here will be this: display: none;  This means that the element is not visible.  Maybe see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008101/how-can-i-get-displaynone-element-using-selenium-webdriver-c  ...or create a hover action first, and use a webdriverwait to get the element.

Comment: Dear pcalkins, this solved the problem!!! Thank you so much!!!